# Electron - Error: Cannot find module nodejavabridge_bindings.node

Tags: node.js, electron

I'm trying to use jdbc in my electron app. After the module installation is completed I've imported it in the `background.js` file of the electron app

When I run the command `npm run electron:serve` I will get this error about a missing module

```js
Error: Cannot find module 'C:\Users\xxx\Desktop\xxx\build\Release\nodejavabridge_bindings.node'
    at webpackEmptyContext (webpack://tool-rifatturazione/./node_modules/java/lib/_sync?:2:10)
    at eval (webpack://tool/./node_modules/java/lib/nodeJavaBridge.js?:21:77)
    at ./node_modules/java/lib/nodeJavaBridge.js (C:\Users\xxx\Desktop\xxx\dist_electron\index.js:1086:1)
    at __webpack_require__ (C:\Users\xxx\Desktop\xxx\dist_electron\index.js:3754:42)
    at eval (webpack://tool/./node_modules/java/index.js?:2:18)
    at ./node_modules/java/index.js (C:\Users\xxx\Desktop\xxx\dist_electron\index.js:1075:1)
    at __webpack_require__ (C:\Users\xxx\Desktop\xxx\dist_electron\index.js:3754:42)
    at eval (webpack://tool/./node_modules/jdbc/lib/jinst.js?:5:12)
    at ./node_modules/jdbc/lib/jinst.js (C:\Users\xxx\Desktop\xxx\dist_electron\index.js:1117:1)
    at __webpack_require__ (C:\Users\xxx\Desktop\xxx\dist_electron\index.js:3754:42)
```

Is there any solution to fix this issue? I'm runing windows 11 and node 18 with electron 24.3.0

Comment: If it's just for JDBC, you might be better off just looking for an appropriate library for NodeJS that will let you connect to your database. (Mind that Java and JavaScript are two very different things.) If it's more than that you want to achieve, please tell us what NPM package you're using that requires `nodejavabridge_bindings`. A search on the NPM index revealed only two packages, neither of which are particularly recent.

Comment: @AlexanderLeithner the problem seems disappeared after I've added `JAVA_HOME` to my system configuration. At the moment the main problem seems to be that the jdbc module is compiled for node 108 and the electron app will require the node module version 114. I've tried to rebuild the module but electron-rebuild will fail due to node gyp issue